# Approve PIM request for Microsoft Entra Roles

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

I used `New-MgRoleManagementDirectoryRoleAssignmentScheduleRequest` to activate a role assignment.
Now this request is pending for approval from another user. I want to automate this approval process.

[image]

I found these resources but I was unable to form a PS request. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/id-governance/privileged-identity-management/pim-approval-workflow#approve-requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have one **PIM request** for Microsoft Entra role that is pending for approval like this:

[image]

To **retrieve** these details via PowerShell, you can run below MS Graph PowerShell command by signing in with **`Approver`** user and note Approval request ID:

```
Connect-MgGraph -Scope "RoleAssignmentSchedule.ReadWrite.Directory","PrivilegedAccess.ReadWrite.AzureAD"
Invoke-MgFilterRoleManagementDirectoryRoleAssignmentScheduleRequestByCurrentUser -Filter "status eq 'PendingApproval'"  -On "principal" | fl
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **approve** this PIM request of Microsoft Entra role via PowerShell, I ran below script and got response like this:

```
Connect-MgGraph -Scope "RoleAssignmentSchedule.ReadWrite.Directory","PrivilegedAccess.ReadWrite.AzureAD"

$params = @{
    reviewResult = "Approve"
    justification = "Trusted User"
}

Update-MgBetaRoleManagementDirectoryRoleAssignmentApprovalStep -ApprovalId $approvalId -ApprovalStepId $approvalStepId -BodyParameter $params
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I checked the same in Portal, role **activated** successfully as below:

[image]